# sympy.init_printing() ignores ipython's precision settings

Tags: python, ipython, sympy

6 years ago, there was a bug filed "sympy.init_printing() ignores ipython's precision settings" on https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/2820

I think there is a workaround using custom printers, but I can not figure out how.
This is a nasty problem, as `iPython` is the most perfect calculator I have come across ever.

Problem can be seen in an `iPython` console session:

```
In [1]: import sympy                                                            

In [2]: %precision 3                                                            
Out[2]: '%.3f'

In [3]: import math                                                             

In [4]: math.pi                                                                 
Out[4]: 3.142

In [5]: sympy.init_printing()                                                   

In [6]: math.pi                                                                 
Out[6]: 3.141592653589793
```

So, calling `sympy.init_printing()` somewhat resets the precision from iPython.

However, `init_printing` ([doc](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/interactive.html?highlight=init_printing#sympy.interactive.printing.init_printing)) has a parameter `pretty_printer`:

```
pretty_printer : function, optional, default=None
                 A custom pretty printer. This should mimic sympy.printing.pretty().
```

Morever, `sympy.printing.pretty` ([doc](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html#sympy.printing.pretty.pretty.pretty)) refers to `pretty_print`, which has a parameter `full_prec`:

```
full_prec : bool or string, optional (default=”auto”)
            Use full precision.
```

But I cannot figure out how to fit things together in `init_printing`.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to extend `PrettyPrinter` class by a `_print_float(self, e)` function which handles printing ordinary `float` (not to confuse with `_print_Float(self, e)` which handles sympy `Float` objects):

```
from sympy.printing.pretty.pretty import PrettyPrinter
from sympy.printing.pretty.pretty_symbology import pretty_use_unicode
from sympy.printing.pretty.stringpict import prettyForm

class MyPrettyPrinter(PrettyPrinter):
    def _print_float(self, e):
       return prettyForm('{:.3f}'.format(e))

def mypretty(expr, **settings):
    """
    https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/2820
    https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/70381f282f2d9d039da860e391fe51649df2779d/sympy/printing/pretty/pretty.py#L2598-L2613
    """
    pp = MyPrettyPrinter(settings)
    #    breakpoint()
    # XXX: this is an ugly hack, but at least it works
    use_unicode = pp._settings['use_unicode']
    uflag = pretty_use_unicode(use_unicode)

    try:
        return pp.doprint(expr)
    finally:
        pretty_use_unicode(uflag)

init_printing(pretty_printer=mypretty)
```